# c# NodaTime change the date format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, mysql, nodatime

I am using NodaTime in most of my code for a project.  I am getting a LocalDateTime as a value and need to change the format to insert it into a MySQL database as a datetime field.

I have seen something with OffSetPattern, but not sure how to use it.

Here is where I am trying to write it to the db.

```
public void SetDataLog(Controller controllerInfo, LocalDateTime time, string count)
{
    var count2 = Convert.ToInt32(count);

    var sql = "INSERT INTO controller_activation_log (controller_id, activations, date_created, date_created_timezone) VALUES(" + controllerInfo.controllerId + ", " + count2 + ", \'" + time + "\', \'UTC\')";
            mysqldb.Write(sql);
}
```

The LocalDateTime format comes out as 04/10/2014 10:45:02 (example)
I need it to be 2014-04-10 10:45:02 as a string.

I have tried to string, but oviously that doesn't work in this case.  I have seen something about creating a pattern and parsing it, but I don't understand how to do it, as I don't see that anywhere in NodaTime??  Still new to NodaTime and c# in general so maybe I am missing something relatively simple.  Can anyone help with getting the format that I need?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
datetimeObj.ToString("s").Replace("T"," ")
```

or you can do a regex:

```
Regex.Replace("04/10/2014 10:45:02",@"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)","$3-$1-$2 $4:$5:$6");
```

Alternatively you can do a `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: I am getting a No overload for Method ToString takes 1 argument.

Comment: Dolt. hit enter:  LocalDateTime newTime = time.ToString("s").Replace("T", " ");

Comment: Understood, but not getting a DateTime, getting a LocalDateTime object back to pass into here.  I Don't have control over the object I am getting back as that is in a reference (dll) written by someone else.

Comment: Wait. I'm coming with a regex for your solution

Comment: Aha!  Thanks, your idea pointed my in the right direction

var newTime = time.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
var newTime2 = newTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Seems to be working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with a `LocalDateTime` and just need to format it as a string in a particular manner, then just do so:

```
string s = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You must pass a format provider, which in your case should be `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

However, you should *not* be passing dates as strings, or be building your SQL statement by inserting string parameters.  Please parameterize your query, and use the appropriate data type!

In MySQL, you should be using the `DATETIME` type (for storing a NodaTime `LocalDateTime`).  See [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) for the different date/time data types.

You will also need to call `.ToDateTimeUnspecified()` when passing in your parameter, as the MySQL client library will not understand Noda Time types, but it *will* understand `DateTime`.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = yourConnection;
cmd.CommandText = yourSQLString; // use parameter placeholders like "@time"
cmd.Prepare();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time.ToDateTimeUnspecified());
// and the rest of your parameters...

cmd.Parameters.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, it's quite strange to be hard-coding 'UTC' as the time zone in your SQL statement, when you started with a `LocalDateTime`.  If you're writing UTC, you should probably be starting with an `Instant`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use this

```
String date = mydate.ToString("u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
date=date.Substring(0,date.Length-1);
```